# Data for non empty table for first start

Tags: swift, core-data

I don't want a user who starts my app for the first time doesn't find an empty table. I can create the data that should be visible in the table. But where should this happen? I'll try that e.g. B. in the viewDidLoad, then the data is generated much more often than intended, logically. It should be done once at the first start. I work with coredata and diffabledatasource.

Answer (score 1):

Well one of the things that I normally do to know if my application is running for the first time is to store a value in User Defaults. You can also store the number of executions your application has had and then implement your logic based on this value. Here I leave you as I would.

To work with the User Defaults I use this library that is great: [SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/sunshinejr/SwiftyUserDefaults)

Create a file named (for example)

> UserDefaults.swift

Inside this file put this code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyUserDefaults

// Define app user defaults keys
extension DefaultsKeys {
    var isFirstAppLaunch: DefaultsKey<Bool> { .init("isFirstAppLaunch", defaultValue: true) }
}
```

Next, in your view controller viewDidLoad you can implement this:

```
import SwiftyUserDefaults

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fillDataInFirstAppLaunch()
}

func fillDataInFirstAppLaunch() {
    // If first execution, then fill CoreData with default values
    if Defaults.isFirstAppLaunch {
        // Set to false to run this code only once (the first app launch)
        Defaults.isFirstAppLaunch = false
            
        // Implement your logic here to fill CoreData
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much, you described that brilliantly. I have already come up with this idea, I was just hoping that there might be a slightly more elegant way. I'll try this out.

Comment: @Nuri Doing this with User Defaults is a pretty standard way. Another thing you could do is simply check if the table or tables you have in CoreData already contain values and if not, fill them in.

Comment: Importing a dependency just to use a user defaults value is overkill.   Just use the native swift API, or wrap it in a property wrapper to allow it to be automated.